# Invalid parameter error when doing python scikit-learn grid-search method

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search, hyperparameters

I am trying to learn how to find the optimal hyperparameters in decision trees classifier using the GridSearchCV() method from scikit-learn.

The problem is it is fine if I am specifying just one parameter's options, it is fine as in the following:

```
print(__doc__)

# Code source: Gael Varoquaux
# Modified for documentation by Jaques Grobler
# License: BSD 3 clause

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

# define classifier
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
y = iris.target

# define parameter values that should be searched
min_samples_split_options = range(2, 4)

# create a parameter grid: map the parameter names to the values that should be saved
param_grid_dt = dict(min_samples_split= min_samples_split_options) # for DT

# instantiate the grid
grid = GridSearchCV(dt, param_grid_dt, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')

# fit the grid with param
grid.fit(X, y)

# view complete results
grid.grid_scores_

'''# examine results from first tuple
print grid.grid_scores_[0].parameters
print grid.grid_scores_[0].cv_validation_scores
print grid.grid_scores_[0].mean_validation_score'''

# examine the best model
print '*******Final results*********'
print grid.best_score_
print grid.best_params_
print grid.best_estimator_
```

Result:

```
None
*******Final results*********
0.68
{'min_samples_split': 3}
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
            min_samples_split=3, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
            presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')
```

But when I add another parameters' options into the mix, it gives me an "invalid parameter" error, as follows:

```
print(__doc__)


# Code source: Gael Varoquaux
# Modified for documentation by Jaques Grobler
# License: BSD 3 clause

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

# define classifier
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
y = iris.target

# define parameter values that should be searched
max_depth_options = range(10, 251) # for DT
min_samples_split_options = range(2, 4)

# create a parameter grid: map the parameter names to the values that should be saved
param_grid_dt = dict(max_depth=max_depth_options, min_sample_split=min_samples_split_options) # for DT

# instantiate the grid
grid = GridSearchCV(dt, param_grid_dt, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')

# fit the grid with param
grid.fit(X, y)

'''# view complete results
grid.grid_scores_

# examine results from first tuple
print grid.grid_scores_[0].parameters
print grid.grid_scores_[0].cv_validation_scores
print grid.grid_scores_[0].mean_validation_score

# examine the best model
print '*******Final results*********'
print grid.best_score_
print grid.best_params_
print grid.best_estimator_'''
```

Result:

```
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KubiK\Desktop\GridSearch_ex6.py", line 31, in <module>
    grid.fit(X, y)
  File "C:\Users\KubiK\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 804, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
  File "C:\Users\KubiK\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 553, in _fit
    for parameters in parameter_iterable
  File "C:\Users\KubiK\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 800, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "C:\Users\KubiK\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 658, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "C:\Users\KubiK\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 566, in _dispatch
    job = ImmediateComputeBatch(batch)
  File "C:\Users\KubiK\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 180, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "C:\Users\KubiK\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 72, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\Users\KubiK\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 1520, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.set_params(**parameters)
  File "C:\Users\KubiK\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 270, in set_params
    (key, self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: Invalid parameter min_sample_split for estimator DecisionTreeClassifier. Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Comment: your code should be `min_samples_split` not `min_sample_split`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a typo in your code, it should be `min_samples_split` not `min_sample_split`.